# What is the easiest way to have multiple eclipse installations using the same eclipse.ini file?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am testing different Eclipse configurations, all of them should be executed with the same JVM (I have many), heap size, and so on...
What is the easiest way to apply general settings to all these Eclipse installations? I read in the `eclipse.ini` documentation that:

> Eclipse startup is controlled by the options in
>   $ECLIPSE_HOME/eclipse.ini. If $ECLIPSE_HOME is not defined, the
>   default eclipse.ini in your Eclipse installation directory (or in the
>   case of Mac, the Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS directory) is used.

So I thought about creating a configuration file:
`~/ECLIPSE_CONFIG/eclipse.ini`

and then pointing `ECLIPSE_HOME` to `~/ECLIPSE_CONFIG`, but not sure if this is a good idea (not sure if `ECLIPSE_HOME` is supposed to point to a full Eclipse installation).

Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Are you using *nix? How about a symbolic link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do that is to use a command line argument:

```
--launcher.ini <location> (Executable)
the location of the product .ini file to use.
If not specified the executable will look for a file beside the launcher with 
the same name and the extension .ini.  (ie eclipse.exe looks for eclipse.ini, 
product.exe looks for product.ini)
```

Reference: [The Eclipse runtime options](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html)